# Remotely Access A Text File That Python Is Presently Accessing Locally

Tags: python, python-3.x

On a local machine there are two files in the same directory:

- `taskrunner.py`
- `namefile.txt`

`taskrunner.py` runs continuously (Python 3.x) and reads a single name from `namefile.txt` once per minute. I want to be able to have someone at a remote location SSH into the local machine and replace the old `namefile.txt` with a new `namefile.txt` without causing any collisions. It is entirely acceptable for `taskrunner.py` to work with the old namefile.txt information until the new `namefile.txt` is in place. What I do not want to have occurred is:

1. Have the `taskrunner.py` throw an exception because `namefile.txt` is present in the process of being replaced

and/or

2. Be unable to insert the new `namefile.txt` because of `taskrunner.py` locks out the remote access.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand SO a little better regarding the editing process and the use of Markdown (which I've never used before). Thanks Yatin and any others who edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical situation where a lock is useful.

You need to create two copies of `namefile.txt`: let's call them `namefile.txt` and `namefileOld.txt`. You also need a locking mechanism that will allow fast updates. For complex operations, you can use Redis. For simple operations like yours, you can probably get away with an environment variable. Let's call it `LOCK`, which can take values `True` and `False`.

When a person wants to write to `namefile.txt`, set `LOCK` to `True`.  Subsequently, set `LOCK` to `False` and overwrite `nameFileOld.txt` with data from `nameFile.txt`.

How `taskrunner.py` should read the data:

1. Read the `LOCK` value.
2. If `LOCK == True`, read from `nameFileOld.txt`
3. else, read form `nameFile.txt`

Comment: Thanks ssm; kind of you. I've been looking into how a person who has remote access via SSH can lock a file (and then unlock it) from the command line. There's a good article at: baeldung.com/linux/file-locking that accomplishes it using flock; also a Bash shell script for testing. This won't be easy with my very limited knowledge of shell scripting. I could not find any resources on how to set a lock using an environment variable.

Comment: You don't need a bash script. A remote user can just set the environment variable `LOCK` to `'True'` with the command `LOCK=True` on the command line. You can look up setting environment variables on UNIX.

Comment: Within your Python file, you need to check the environment variable `LOCK`, with the command `import os; os.getenv('LOCK')`.

Comment: You should be able to combine the above methods to implement the result.

Comment: Great advice. Thank you so much ssm. Tom.